# return int from within if statement in a loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

i have a loop which iterates equal to the length of an array, inside this loop i have a method which do some processing and have if-else structure inside. i want that if certain condition is true, then re-iterate the whole loop else continue.
the Minimum working code is provided.

```
for(int xx=0;xx<temp.length;xx++)
    {
     rule=temp[xx][1]; 
     cons=temp[xx][2];
     fp.factprocess(fact, rule, vars, cons);
    }
```

contents of fp.factprocess are like

```
if(condition==true)
  make xx = 0 in the parent loop
else
 continue
```

i dont know how do i do it, i used return statement but it has to be in the end and can not be in the if-block.

Comment: OK .... thanks for sharing.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a boolean from the condition test. If boolean true, set xx to -1 (to be incremented to 0) in the loop.

```
for(int xx=0;xx<temp.length;xx++)
    {
     rule=temp[xx][1]; 
     cons=temp[xx][2];
     boolean setXXtoZero = fp.factprocess(fact, rule, vars, cons);
     if(setXXtoZero) xx=-1;

    }
```

fp.factprocess:

```
return condition;
```

Comment: you may want to rewrite that last part as: 'return condition;'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there can be a return statement in the if block.

```
public int getValue(int val){
  if ( value == 5 ){
    return value;
  }
  else{
    return 6;
  }
}
```

for instance, is valid Java code.

```
public int getValue(int input){
  if ( input == 5 ){
    return input;
  }
}
```

on the other hand, is not, since you don't return anything if input does not equal 5, yet the method has to either return an int, or throw an Exception.

That's probably what your problem is: you need to provide a return statement for all possible scenario's.

Comment: Thanks i will give it a try and update you, does it has to return in every possible scenario? as i dont want to return any thing in the else-block

Comment: you must either return something, or throw an exception to interrupt the method. best is to return a value

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the `xx` variable of the loop, I suggest to return a boolean in your `factprocess` method.

```
for (int xx = 0; xx < temp.length; xx++) {
  rule = temp[xx][1]; 
  cons = temp[xx][2];
  boolean shouldRestart = fp.factprocess(fact, rule, vars, cons);
  if (shouldRestart) {
    xx = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `xx` to `factprocess()` and assign the return to `xx`

```
for(int xx=0;xx<temp.length;xx++)
    {
     rule=temp[xx][1]; 
     cons=temp[xx][2];
     xx = fp.factprocess(fact, rule, vars, cons, xx);
    }
```

Inside `factprocces()`

```
if (condition == true) {
    return 0
} else {
    return xx
}
```